# Groupby a column and then compare two other columns and return a value in a different column

Tags: python, pandas, dfply

I have a dataframe similar to this

```
    data={'COMB':["PNR1", "PNR1", "PNR11", "PNR2", "PNR2"],
        'FROM':["MAA", "BLR", "DEL", "TRV", "HYD"],
         'TO':["BLR", "MAA", "MAA", "HYD", "TRV"]}
md=pd.DataFrame(data)
md
```

What I want to do is to create another column based on the condition that if the From of one row is equal to the To of the next row, then it sholud return "R" otherwise it will return "O" in the new column.
My final output should look like this.
[image]

Can anyone help me in python. I tried following method, but it gives me error

```
md_merged=(md>>
            group_by('COMB')>>
            mutate(TYPE=np.where(md['FROM'].isin(md['TO']),"R","O"))>>
           ungroup)
```

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution compare all values between groups, not only prvious and next.

You can use custom lambda function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) for boolean mask, for avoid `MultiIndex` is added `group_keys=False` to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), last set new values in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = md.groupby('COMB', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x['FROM'].isin(x['TO']))
md = md.assign(Type=np.where(mask,"R","O"))
print (md)
    COMB FROM   TO Type
0   PNR1  MAA  BLR    R
1   PNR1  BLR  MAA    R
2  PNR11  DEL  MAA    O
3   PNR2  TRV  HYD    R
4   PNR2  HYD  TRV    R
```

---

This solution compare previous and next rows per groups:

Another idea is use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), it should be faster like `groupby.apply`:

```
mask = (md.groupby('COMB')['FROM'].shift().eq(md['TO']) | 
        md.groupby('COMB')['TO'].shift(-1).eq(md['FROM']))

md = md.assign(Type=np.where(mask,"R","O"))
print (md)
    COMB FROM   TO Type
0   PNR1  MAA  BLR    R
1   PNR1  BLR  MAA    R
2  PNR11  DEL  MAA    O
3   PNR2  TRV  HYD    R
4   PNR2  HYD  TRV    R
```

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you. Can you please explain the code?

Comment: Using numpy would be much faster

Comment: @wwnde - if  for each `COMB`  are unique pairs `from` and `to` then yes. If multiple pairs then not, if multiple `COMB` with same `from` and `to` then not. Depends of data

Comment: I get the point